# Nested model in Wagtail Orderable

Tags: django, model, nested, wagtail

In Wagtail, I'm trying to create a Page that using Orderable model of Wagtail. And in that Orderable model, I'm trying to nest the "ImageWithAltText", the reason for this is because by default, Wagtail image does not provide alt text field. So I would like to create my own class for re-use anywhere that has image.

Below is the code:

```
class ImageWithAltText(models.Model):
    image = models.ForeignKey(
        "wagtailimages.Image",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name="+",
    )
    image_alt_text = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    panels = [
        FieldPanel("image"),
        FieldPanel("image_alt_text"),
    ]


class FAQItem(Orderable):
    page = ParentalKey("get_the_facts.GetTheFactPage", related_name="faq_items")
    media_file = models.ForeignKey(ImageWithAltText, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=False)
  
    panels = [
        FieldPanel("media_file"),
        FieldPanel("title"),
    ]


class GetTheFactPage(Page):

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        InlinePanel("faq_items", label="FAQ"),
    ]
```

I have no succeed with this, at the Admin site, the UI the not showing "image" and "image_alt_text" as expected. Please take a look at the picture below:
[image]

I haven't had any clue why this happened yet. Please help me with this, thank you in advanced.